# Serverless.yml Aurora RDS: Infrastructure as code

Tags: serverless-framework, amazon-aurora

I'm looking for a way to declare via serverless.yml an Aurora DB with all the tables.

I would like to be able to deploy via `serverless deploy` a new Aurora instance with all the tables.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way I found is to declare the aurora DB resource with a YAML like:

```
Resources:
  RDSCluster:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    Properties:
      MasterUsername: ${self:custom.dbLogin} 
      MasterUserPassword: ${self:custom.dbPassword} 
      DatabaseName: MagaDB
      Engine: aurora
      EngineMode: serverless
      ScalingConfiguration:
        AutoPause: true
        MaxCapacity: 2
        MinCapacity: 1
        SecondsUntilAutoPause: 300
      EnableHttpEndpoint: true
      StorageEncrypted: true
```

And then create an init.sql script that will instantiate all the tables.

The difference between Aurora and DynamoDB is that you need to declare tables when deploying a DynamoDB but you don't need to with Aurora.

Answer (score 3):

To do this with the Serverless Framework, you'll need to write a CloudFormation template and include it inside the `resources` block of your `serverless.yml` file.

Here are the docs, so you can learn more about including [CloudFormation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources/) in your `serverless.yml` file.

Here's a set of [examples](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-aurora-cloudformation-samples) from AWS that can help, although they're extremely verbose and include lots of extra things you may not need.

Comment: Thanks ! In the repo you gave I also found https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-aurora-serverless-data-api-sam which shows you how to deploy an aurora DB with the new Data API support which allows you to not keep a connection alive.